# Psycopg2 INSERT variables, string format error

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am trying to update a row of a Postgresql table. I am using Psycopg2 and Python3.

I receive the error:
"TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

code:
self.cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO blacklisted_ips (ip, source_id, date_created, date_modified) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);", ["address_list"])

ip, source_id, date_created, date_modified are the column names.

passing a list of tuples
address_list sample data:
('223.223.202.183', 29, '2018-06-28 12:32:02', '2018-06-28 12:32:02')

I can't figure out why I get this error. I'm guessing it is centered around the place holders after "VALUES".  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code says `["address_list"]`. That means you’re passing a list containing a single element, which is the string `address_list`. Did you mean to pass the variable `address_list` instead?

Comment: ah ok, I need to pass the variable that points to the list.  I have:

def add_ips(self, address_list):

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `address_list` is a list of values to be inserted, you can pass it directly to `executemany`:

```
self.cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO blacklisted_ips (ip, source_id, date_created, date_modified) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);", address_list)
```

(Note the lack of quotes and brackets around `address_list`.)

Comment: Thank you so much. That was my issue, the brackets around the variable.

Comment: Glad I could help! You can check the box next to the answer to accept it.